# MongoDB: Find (and all variations) returns no results, but the document is in the collection

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So... This is a bit of a weird one.

I'm implementing a database in MongoDB atlas and my API calls the database to login etc. This has been working smoothly except for one account. With this account, the database cannot find the phone number, even though I can plainly see it exists in the database.

In the terminal,

```
db.callers.find({"fullName": "John Doe"})
```

returns

```
{
    "fullName" : "John Doe",
    "phoneNo" : "07123456789"
}
```

but

```
db.callers.find({"phoneNo" : "07123456789"})
```

returns nothing.
Am I missing something? I've searched everywhere but I can't find anything detailing why this could be going wrong.

Comment: Was there a hard shutdown at some point? Or trouble with the server?

Comment: Not as far as I know, the weird thing for me is that one returns the document, the other doesn't - so the data is definitely there

Comment: Are both fields the same type? Maybe into DB ```phoneNo``` is an integer and are you looking for a ```string```?

Comment: To check, I've just deleted and reenetered the document manually, and I'm having the same issue. Could it be to do with the individual phone number (sufficed to say, this person's real number is not 07123456789)?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought mongo would allow ints to start with a 0, as all phone numbers in this country do (In the uk, all mobile phone numbers start 07, and all landlines start 0).

Comment: Are you running a standalone server or replica set?

Comment: Replica set afaik

Comment: Thanks for the advice re: MongoDB Devs, I've asked in their forum and am waiting on a response - I'll post an answer here (if I get one)

Comment: @EwanSpence amazing, you're welcome.

Comment: @EwanSpence if you run `db.collection.find(yourquery).explain().queryPlanner` does it appear different for this phone number? respect to the others

Comment: @Minsky Doesn't seem to, no...

Comment: Just posting a comment to say that nothing has come from the MongoDB forums and I still don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: I believe this has nothing to with the number but with a crash at some point. I'd try this: run `mongodump` on that db, and get the collection out of the cluster. Then, run mongorestore using  `--dump` flag. This will re-create any indexes, and update any metadata tables

Comment: Sorry, i meant the `--drop` flag. be careful cause 1. exporting twice to the same folder overwrites the folder (named dump by default). 2. `--drop` the wrong collection I presume deletes the collection. But it's worth try IMHO.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of doing this unless I absolutely have to. I have deleted and reentered the document in question multiple times and it's not fixed it - would this `mongodump` still work?

Comment: Well, it's difficult to know, but worth a try. You could do `mongodump` and then `mongorestore` to a complete different (test) cluster or database. Just use a random email you have and create a free cluster in Atlas, for example.